# jQuery .hover() and .click() not working

Tags: jquery, html, click, hover

I'm trying to add a simple hover and click function to a part of my page and it's not working. I've done this hundred of times with no problem but this time is different and I can't find out why?

HTML:

```
<div class="description">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <p>bla bla bla</p>
        <div class="linkDesc">
            <a href="#">bla bla bla</a>
        </div>
        <div class="plusSign">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    $('#wrapper').hover(function () {
        $('this').addClass('hover');
    }, function () {
        $('this').removeClass('hover');
    });
    $('#wrapper').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var urlLocation = $('this').find('.linkDesc').children('a').attr('href');
        window.location = urlLocation;
    });
});
```

Comment: the selector of this shouldn't be wrapped by quotes 
$(this), not $('this')

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('this')   // You have enclosed it as as a string
            // It will try to look for tagName called this
```

should be

```
$(this)    // Removing the Quotes should work
```

Only legal `TagNames , classNames , psuedo Selectors and Id's` are supposed to be enclosed in **Quotes**..

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/hQD2P/)**

Comment: I should have seen it! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$('this')` with `$(this)`

Answer (score 0):

if you need only add/remove class, then you can set hover with css:

```
#wrapper:hover {
    background: red;
}
```